# ¿Como personalizo el aspecto de un JScrollBar contenido en un JScrollPane?

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

### Contexto

Quería mostrar una imagen dentro de un panel, pero el panel es mas pequeño que la imagen, en ancho. Por lo que quiero usar un  `JScrollPane`  para que se pueda desplazar la imagen, pero resulta que en el panel tengo otros componentes, entonces quiero cambiar el diseño del  `JScrollPane` y adaptarlo a mi gusto.

#### Problemas

**1.** Primero no podía acomodar la posición de la imagen a mi gusto dentro del  `JScrollPane` , por lo que tuve que crear un  `JViewPort`  para anular como mostraba la imagen por defecto, y hacer que pinte la imagen en relación a la ubicación del "track" del  `JScrollBar` y en la  posición "y" en que yo quería, no se si es lo mas optimo pero a la vista de lo mal diseñado que esta la personalización de componentes en java es la única forma que conseguí hacerlo, eso por una parte, me gustaría saber si hay alguna forma mas "profesional" de hacerlo.

**2.** Por otro lado y lo que mas me importa arreglar, es el  `JScrollBar` en sentido horizontal del  `JScrollPane`, ya que el que esta por defecto queda muy mal en mi panel, es demasiado grande y cuadrado, para lo que yo quiero. Para corregirlo tome la mala decisión de intentar usar las UI q trae java(muy mal diseñadas por cierto), pero solo logre cambiarle el alto, y la forma, pero no puedo cambiarle el ancho, y tampoco puedo cambiarle el fondo, intente de todo pero no funciona.

#### Pruebas

Para que no me den soluciones que ya intente:

**1.** **Ancho JScrollBar**: Probe simplemente usando un  `setPreferedSize();`  de hecho se puede ver en el código que ya lo uso, pero sin embargo, el ancho no cambia.

**2.** **Ancho JScrollBar horizontal**: Intente sobreescribir el metodo  `layoutHScrollBar()`  y funciono, pero el "track" de la barra sobrepasa los limites del ancho que tiene el  `JScrollBar` , probe un `setSize();` tampoco funciono, probe usando el  `paint()`  pero devuelta lo mismo de los limites.

**3.** **El fondo del JScrollBar**: Por alguna razón aunque le ponga  `setOpaque(false);`  el fondo se mantiene blanco, en vez de ser transparente, probe usando el  `paint()`  pero tapa el  "track", además se bugea.

**4.**  **El fondo del JScrollBar**: Probe con el método `LookAndFell.installColors();` y el  `LookAndFell.installOpaque();`  pero por supuesto, como la maravilla que es java, no funciono.

#### Post data

Tal vez este usando mal las cosas, pero no hay mucha información al respecto, incluso le pregunte al tan "inteligente" ChatGPT y solo perdí el tiempo, me hacia cosas sin sentido. En fin como lo puedo hacer?
Antes de que me digan que revise la documentación, lo hice. Pero para ser sinceros es bastante pobre, al final te las tienes que rebuscar solo.

#### Imagenes del problema

Asi estaba antes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá una imagen del resultado final, al que llegue:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán ahí esta el fondo blanco/gris donde esta contenido el "track"(la barra redondeada de color gris oscuro) que no pude quitar, y también se puede ver por ese mismo fondo blanco que el ancho del `JScrollBar` ocupa todo el ancho del panel, lo cual quiero cambiar. Lo de arriba con letras, es la imagen, que como verán no cabe en el componente.

Asi quiero que quede:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las líneas rojas, son solo de referencia, quiero que los limites del `JScrollBar` sean donde están esas líneas. A su vez obviamente la barra gris oscuro, seguramente deba tener otro tamaño en relación a ese limite, porque sino no se recorre toda la imagen.

Aquí la clase:

```java
package interfaz.componentes.barras.componentes_admconectores;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;

import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JViewport;
import javax.swing.LookAndFeel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.ViewportUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicViewportUI;

import logica.Grabador;
import logica.MouseClicker;
import utilidades.Trace;

public class ConectorVisual extends JLabel {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private int id = 0;
   private Icon elm = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/conElm.png"));
   private Icon elmRojo = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/conElmR.png"));
   private Icon lapizAbajo = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/lapizAbajo.png"));
   private JCheckBox visibilidad = new JCheckBox(new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/ojo.png")));
   private JButton eliminar = new JButton(elm);
   private JButton editar = new JButton(lapizAbajo);
   private JScrollPane contenedorRep;
   private JComponent representacionConector;
   private Image asd;

   public ConectorVisual(int ide, JComponent rep) {
       setOpaque(true);
       setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
       setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
       setMinimumSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
       setMaximumSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
       setLayout(null);
       setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
       setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

       id = ide;

       representacionConector = rep;
       try {

           asd = ((ImageIcon) ((JLabel) representacionConector).getIcon()).getImage();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO: handle exception
       }
       // JComponent panel = new JLabel();
       representacionConector.setLocation(0, 20);
       // panel.setLayout(null);
       // panel.setSize(representacionConector.getWidth(),
       // representacionConector.getHeight());
       // panel.setVisible(true);
       // panel.setOpaque(true);
       // panel.setLocation(10, 10);

       iniciarComponentes();
       iniciarEventos();
   }

   private void iniciarEventos() {
       new Eventos();
   }

   private void iniciarComponentes() {
       configConmutarVisibilidad();
       configEliminar();
       configEditar();
       configRepDeConector();
   }

   private void configRepDeConector() {
       contenedorRep = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
               JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
       contenedorRep.setBounds(1, 1, getPreferredSize().width - 2, getPreferredSize().height - 2);
       contenedorRep.setOpaque(false);
       contenedorRep.setVerticalScrollBar(new CustomScrollBar(JScrollBar.VERTICAL));
       contenedorRep.setHorizontalScrollBar(new CustomScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL));
       contenedorRep.setViewport(new prueba());
       add(contenedorRep);
       contenedorRep.repaint();
   }

   private void configConmutarVisibilidad() {
       visibilidad.setBounds(45, 1, 17, 14);
       visibilidad.setBorder(null);
       visibilidad.setContentAreaFilled(false);
       visibilidad.setOpaque(false);
       visibilidad.setFocusable(false);
       visibilidad.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/ojoCerrado.png")));
       add(visibilidad);
   }

   private void configEliminar() {
       eliminar.setBounds(63, 1, 14, 14);
       eliminar.setOpaque(false);
       eliminar.setFocusable(false);
       eliminar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
       eliminar.setBorder(null);
       add(eliminar);
   }

   private void configEditar() {
       editar.setBounds(32, 1, 14, 14);
       editar.setBorder(null);
       editar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
       editar.setFocusable(false);
       editar.setOpaque(false);
       add(editar);
   }

   public void efectoSeleccion() {
       if (getBorder() == null) {
           setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
       } else {
           setBorder(null);
       }
   }

   public void actualizarVisibilidad() {
       visibilidad.doClick();
   }

   public final void setId(int id) {
       this.id = id;
   }

   public final int getId() {
       return id;
   }

   public JCheckBox getBotonVisibilidad() {
       return visibilidad;
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);

       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2d.setFont(new Font("arial black", Font.PLAIN, 14));
       g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
       String numero = "" + id;
       g2d.drawString(numero, 69 - 8 * (numero.length() - 1), 77);
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return id + "  " + ConectorVisual.class.toGenericString();
   }

   private class prueba extends JViewport {

       public prueba() {
           super();
           setView(representacionConector);

       }

       @Override
       public void paint(Graphics g) {
           g.drawImage(asd, -getViewPosition().x,
                   15, null);
       }

   }

   private class CustomScrollBar extends JScrollBar {

       private static final int SCROLLBAR_SIZE = 10;

       public CustomScrollBar(int orientation) {
           super(orientation);
           setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, SCROLLBAR_SIZE));
           setUI(new RoundedScrollbarUI());

       }

       private class RoundedScrollbarUI extends BasicScrollBarUI {

           private static final int SCROLLBAR_WIDTH = 55;
           private static final int SCROLLBAR_HEIGHT = 10;

           @Override
           protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
               int arc = thumbBounds.height / 2;
               Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
               g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
               RoundRectangle2D thumbShape = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(thumbBounds.x, thumbBounds.y + 4,
                       thumbBounds.width - 15, thumbBounds.height - 5, arc, arc);
               g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
               g2.fill(thumbShape);
               g2.dispose();
           }

           @Override
           public void installUI(JComponent c) {
               super.installUI(c);
               c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(5, 10));
           }

           @Override
           protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
               return createZeroButton();
           }

           @Override
           protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
               return createZeroButton();
           }

           private JButton createZeroButton() {
               JButton button = new JButton();
               Dimension zeroDim = new Dimension(0, 0);
               button.setPreferredSize(zeroDim);
               button.setMinimumSize(zeroDim);
               button.setMaximumSize(zeroDim);
               return button;
           }

h

       }
   }

   private class Eventos {

       public Eventos() {
           conmutarVisibilidadConectores();
           eliminarConector();
           editarConector();
       }

       private void conmutarVisibilidadConectores() {
           visibilidad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   if (visibilidad.isSelected()) {
                       Grabador.ConectoresGestionados.get(id - 1).setVisible(false);
                   } else {
                       Grabador.ConectoresGestionados.get(id - 1).setVisible(true);
                   }
               }
           });
       }

       private void eliminarConector() {
           eliminar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                   eliminar.setIcon(elmRojo);
               }

               @Override
               public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                   eliminar.setIcon(elm);
               }
           });
           eliminar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                   MouseClicker.ESPACIO_DE_TRABAJO.eliminarConector(Grabador.ConectoresGestionados.get(id
                           - 1));
               }
           });
       }

       private void editarConector() {
           editar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
               Icon lapizArriba = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/lapizArriba.png"));

               @Override
               public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                   editar.setIcon(lapizArriba);
               }

               @Override
               public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                   editar.setIcon(lapizAbajo);
               }
           });
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner una o más imágenes de como esperas ver el resultado?

Comment: si claro, añadido

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NOTA: Bueno después de mucho insistir, pude conseguir algo bastante funcional, el único problema es que si se añaden muchos componentes, la barra se hace tan pequeña que desaparece.

Lo que hice resumidamente fue "ir a lo bruto", sobrescribiendo los métodos de
`setSize()`, `setBounds()` del `JScrollBar` para que únicamente tomara siempre los mismos valores q yo quería, sin importar el valor que reciba al llamarse el método. Por otra parte, necesitaba que a medida q se agregaran componentes el tamaño de la barra se ajustara para que al desplazarla se pudiesen llegar a ver todos los componentes, eso lo hace java por defecto, pero debido a los requisitos que yo quería, es decir, que el contenedor de la barra tuviera un tamaño específicos que no es el que asigna por defecto java, por lo tanto al hacer esos cálculos, los hacia mal. Lo que hice sobrescribir el método que hace esos cálculos, cambiar el tamaño del componente, y luego llamar a al método `super()` de ese método para que se ejecuten los cálculos necesarios pero con el tamaño de la barra cambiado.

Aquí la clase por así a alguien le sirve:

```java
package interfaz.componentes.barras.componentes_admconectores;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI;
import logica.Grabador;
import logica.MouseClicker;

public class ConectorVisual extends JLabel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id = 0;
    private Icon elm = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/conElm.png"));
    private Icon elmRojo = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/conElmR.png"));
    private Icon lapizAbajo = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/lapizAbajo.png"));
    private JCheckBox visibilidad = new JCheckBox(new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/ojo.png")));
    private JButton eliminar = new JButton(elm);
    private JButton editar = new JButton(lapizAbajo);
    private JLabel representacionConector;
    private JScrollPane contenedorRep;

    public ConectorVisual(int ide, JLabel rep) {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
        setMinimumSize(getPreferredSize());
        setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());
        setSize(80, 80);
        setLayout(null);
        setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        id = ide;
        representacionConector = rep;

        iniciarComponentes();
        iniciarEventos();
    }

    private void iniciarEventos() {
        new Eventos();
    }

    private void iniciarComponentes() {
        configConmutarVisibilidad();
        configEliminar();
        configEditar();
        if (representacionConector.getSize().width > getWidth()) {
            configRepDeConectorLargo();
            repaint();
        } else {
            configRepDeConector();
        }
    }

    private void configRepDeConector() {
        representacionConector.setLocation((getWidth() - representacionConector.getWidth()) / 2,
                (getHeight() - representacionConector.getHeight()) / 2 + 7);
        if (representacionConector.getHeight() > getPreferredSize().height - 28) {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getPreferredSize().width,
                    (representacionConector.getHeight() - (getPreferredSize().height - 28))
                            + getPreferredSize().height + 5));
            setMinimumSize(getPreferredSize());
            setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());
            setSize(getPreferredSize());
        }
        add(representacionConector);
    }

    private void configRepDeConectorLargo() {
        contenedorRep = new JScrollPane(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        contenedorRep.setBorder(null);
        contenedorRep.setHorizontalScrollBar(new ScrollBarPersonalizada(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL));
        contenedorRep.setVerticalScrollBar(new ScrollBarPersonalizada(JScrollBar.VERTICAL));
        contenedorRep.setOpaque(false);
        contenedorRep.getViewport().setOpaque(false);
        contenedorRep.getViewport().setView(representacionConector);
        contenedorRep.setBounds(2, 17, getPreferredSize().width - 4, getPreferredSize().height - 19);
        cambiarTamano();
        contenedorRep.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                efectoSeleccion();
            }
        });
        add(contenedorRep);
    }

    private void cambiarTamano() {
        contenedorRep.setSize(contenedorRep.getWidth(), contenedorRep.getViewport().getView().getHeight() + 18);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(getWidth(), contenedorRep.getY() + contenedorRep.getHeight() + 1));
        for (Component camUbic : representacionConector.getComponents()) {
            camUbic.setLocation(camUbic.getX(),
                    contenedorRep.getViewport().getView().getHeight() / 2 - camUbic.getHeight() / 2 + 3);
        }
        setSize(getPreferredSize());
        setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());
        setMinimumSize(getPreferredSize());
    }

    private void configConmutarVisibilidad() {
        visibilidad.setBounds(45, 1, 17, 14);
        visibilidad.setBorder(null);
        visibilidad.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        visibilidad.setOpaque(false);
        visibilidad.setFocusable(false);
        visibilidad.setSelectedIcon(new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/ojoCerrado.png")));
        add(visibilidad);
    }

    private void configEliminar() {
        eliminar.setBounds(63, 1, 14, 14);
        eliminar.setOpaque(false);
        eliminar.setFocusable(false);
        eliminar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        eliminar.setBorder(null);
        add(eliminar);
    }

    private void configEditar() {
        editar.setBounds(32, 1, 14, 14);
        editar.setBorder(null);
        editar.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        editar.setFocusable(false);
        editar.setOpaque(false);
        add(editar);
    }

    public void efectoSeleccion() {
        if (getBorder() == null) {
            setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        } else {
            setBorder(null);
        }
    }

    public void actualizarVisibilidad() {
        visibilidad.doClick();
    }

    public final void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public final int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public JCheckBox getBotonVisibilidad() {
        return visibilidad;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setFont(new Font("arial black", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        g2d.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        String numero = "" + id;
        g2d.drawString(numero, 69 - 8 * (numero.length() - 1), getPreferredSize().height - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + "  " + ConectorVisual.class.toGenericString();
    }

    private class ScrollBarPersonalizada extends JScrollBar {

        public ScrollBarPersonalizada(int orientation) {
            super(orientation);
            setSize(64, 10);
            setUI(new ScrollBarRedondeada());
            setOpaque(true);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void setSize(Dimension d) {
            d.setSize(64, 10);
            super.setSize(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void setSize(int width, int height) {
            super.setSize(64, 10);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            super.setBounds(x, y, 64, 10);
        }

        private class ScrollBarRedondeada extends BasicScrollBarUI {

            @Override
            protected void paintThumb(Graphics g, JComponent c, Rectangle thumbBounds) {
                int arc = thumbBounds.height / 2;
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                RoundRectangle2D thumbShape = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(thumbBounds.x, thumbBounds.y + 4,
                        thumbBounds.width - 15, thumbBounds.height - 5, arc, arc);
                g2.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
                g2.fill(thumbShape);
                g2.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            protected JButton createDecreaseButton(int orientation) {
                return createZeroButton();
            }

            @Override
            protected JButton createIncreaseButton(int orientation) {
                return createZeroButton();
            }

            private JButton createZeroButton() {
                JButton button = new JButton();
                Dimension zeroDim = new Dimension(0, 0);
                button.setPreferredSize(zeroDim);
                button.setMinimumSize(zeroDim);
                button.setMaximumSize(zeroDim);
                return button;
            }

            @Override
            protected void layoutHScrollbar(JScrollBar sb) {
                sb.setSize(64, 10);
                sb.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(64, 10));
                super.layoutHScrollbar(sb);
            }

            @Override
            public Dimension getMaximumThumbSize() {
                return scrollbar.getPreferredSize();
            }

            @Override
            protected void configureScrollBarColors() {
                scrollbar.setBackground(ConectorVisual.this.getBackground());
            }
        }
    }

    private class Eventos {

        public Eventos() {
            conmutarVisibilidadConectores();
            eliminarConector();
            editarConector();
            actualizarTamanoConector();
        }

        private void conmutarVisibilidadConectores() {
            visibilidad.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (visibilidad.isSelected()) {
                        Grabador.ConectoresGestionados.get(id - 1).setVisible(false);
                    } else {
                        Grabador.ConectoresGestionados.get(id - 1).setVisible(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        private void eliminarConector() {
            eliminar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    eliminar.setIcon(elmRojo);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    eliminar.setIcon(elm);
                }
            });
            eliminar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    MouseClicker.ESPACIO_DE_TRABAJO.eliminarConector(Grabador.ConectoresGestionados.get(id
                            - 1));
                }
            });
        }

        private void editarConector() {
            editar.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                Icon lapizArriba = new ImageIcon(ConectorVisual.class.getResource("/lapizArriba.png"));

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    editar.setIcon(lapizArriba);
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    editar.setIcon(lapizAbajo);
                }
            });
        }

        private void actualizarTamanoConector() {
            representacionConector.addPropertyChangeListener("icon", new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if (contenedorRep == null) {
                        if (getPreferredSize().width < representacionConector.getWidth()) {
                            remove(representacionConector);
                            configRepDeConectorLargo();
                            contenedorRep.repaint();
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (((Icon) evt.getOldValue()).getIconHeight() < representacionConector.getIcon()
                                .getIconHeight()) {
                            cambiarTamano();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

PD: Gracias a... nadie. Lo tuve que descubrir solo.